Does Intel SGX SDK check invalid memory access from untrusted app to enclave in simulation mode? If not, any alternative method to check?
I saw this answer to a similar question.
However, I am still wondering if the SDK in simulation mode will recognize invalid access from untrusted app to the enclave memory and report such an incident.
It would be frustrating if the simulation mode works ok, but the code actually cannot run on SGX-supported hardware, because of mistakenly implemented invalid access from untrusted code to enclave memory.
I encounter this confusion when implementing some simple data access ocalls.
The ocall in EDL file:
void ocall_get_data3([user_check]unsigned char** data_buffer, size_t data_size, uint64_t pk);

The handling code in untrusted app:
void ocall_get_data3(unsigned char** data_buffer, size_t data_size, uint64_t pk) {
    printf("ptr %p %p\n", data_buffer, *data_buffer);
    *data_buffer = data_map[pk];
    printf("ptr %p %p\n", data_buffer, *data_buffer);
}

The enclave code calling this ocall:
    //...
    uint8_t *p_encrypted_data={};
    uint8_t** pp = &p_encrypted_data;
    ocall_printf("ptr %p %p\n", pp, *pp); // a print ocall
    ocall_get_data3(pp, encrypted_len, pk);

Since I used user_check tag in the EDL definition, the bridge passed the pointers through untouched.
The printed result showed that data_buffer was the same pointer as inside the enclave but its value *data_buffer is altered in the untrusted app.
ptr 0x7f4286adca38 0x0                // the pointer inside enclave
ptr 0x7f4286adca38 (nil)              // the pointer outside before assignment
ptr 0x7f4286adca38 0x5627b19644f0     // the pointer outside after assignment

There was no exception raised in simulation mode during execution.
Though I don't have SGX-enabled hardware, I guess this behavior is not the same as in hardware mode.
However, I am not confident if my testing, observation, and reasoning is correct.
Hence, I came up with this question to confirm (i) if SGX simulation mode can help recognize such memory access errors, and (ii) if not, is there alternative method for developers to recognize and fix such bugs without SGX hardware?

Side note: know that SGX is deprecated by Intel, at least for client CPUs, since 2021.
